# Email Through Terminal in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, email, shell, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I want to write an automated shell script for sending email by specifying the sender email address as well as receiver's email address ...
I tried using mailx but to  no use..
Please Help !!!

Comment: What did you try?  Show us your code, the error it produced, and describe what you expected to happen.

Comment: Not much to go on here... what do you what it to do, how are you specifying the dress? what code did you use?

Comment: I got it fixed using smtp :) anyways thanks a lot